# Can I activate an interrupted audio session without deactive the current one?

Tags: ios, session, audio

Say there are two apps on my iPhone. One is a music player developed by others, the other is developed by me. After my app interrupts the music player's audio session, I want to re-active its audio session without de-activating my app's audio session.

Two questions:
1. Is it workable?

2. If not, are there any other ways to finish the task?[I don't want to give up my audio session because my app should record all the time.]

In a word, is there other way to reactive interrupted audio session except running "setActive:NO" in current session?

Hope someone can help me. Thx